# Google apps script - adding a pop up calendar to dialog box

Tags: google-apps-script

I' have created the script to the google excel that when user clicks on particular button, dialog box pop up and demands to enter date.Date is entered by user manually (from keyboard). And i wonder if there is possibility to add to this dialog box a small pop up calendar to choose date from, instead of writing it.
Thanks in advance for any help :D

Comment: You can create custom dialogs with HtmlService which for the most part just boils down to proper use of css, javascript and html

Comment: Could you add your own code, or an example, so we can better help you?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for long wait, but here i include code that is responsible for pop up dialog box.

```
  function podaj_date() 
    {
      var plik = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
      var arkusz = plik.getActiveSheet(); 
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  
      var result=ui.prompt('Podaj date',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL); 
      var button = result.getSelectedButton(); 
      var text = result.getResponseText();  
      if(button==ui.Button.OK) 
      {
        arkusz.getRange("F3").setValue(text); 
        if(text.length<8) 
        {
          ui.alert('Podano złą date'); 
          podaj_date.call();
        }
      }else 
      {
        ui.alert('Nie podano daty');
        podaj_date.call();
      }
    }
```